# VMWare Play Cannot Install On 15.04

Tags: vmware

When I try to install `VMWare` Player, it asks to compile modules and fails at the step `Starting VMWare Services` with the following error:

```
2015-04-29T18:43:24.520-07:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with VMware module vmnet, and Linux Kernels 3.19 and later. The instructions to fix this are on the [Arch WiKi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels_and_up)